# How to run osrm in https using docker

Tags: docker, osrm

These lines of codes create a local http server, I want it in https (self cert)

```
wget https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/sri-lanka-latest.osm.pbf

docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/sri-lanka-latest.osm.pbf

docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-partition /data/sri-lanka-latest.osrm

docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-customize /data/sri-lanka-latest.osrm

docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/sri-lanka-latest.osrm
```

I was given this task even though I have no idea how network works, I did a few research but still confuse, sorry and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`osrm-backend` is a development server and does not support TLS. You should either run it behind reverse TLS proxy like `nginx` or use different server. See [this thread](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/4537) for the additional information.

Comment: I have two more question, 1) how will the docker run  code looks like if I were using Nginx and 2) From where I should start studying Nginx

Comment: 2) https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx